# Open a shell script in gui

Tags: command-line, .sh

I want to run a shell script. Its a .sh-file. If i make double click, it opens the file in gedit. I know how to execute it in the terminal, but thats a huge way to get every time in the right directory and find the right path. If i make the check in the properties of the file "Run executable files when they are opened." it changes nothing. It opens still in gedit and i dont know how to change it. I tried it with the ubuntu tweak tool, but i cant delete the default opener of this filetype. Its not especially one file, its the whole filetype.

Answer (score 0):

You want to run script from a folder, right? In that case you need to open file manager, go to Edit drop-down  menu -> properties -> behavior, and check "Run executable files when they are opened." But pay attention, if a script doesn't call for an xterm or anything like that to open, you won't see the script running step by step

Comment: I made there already a check. If i start it over the terminal, it works. But if i make double click it opens everytime in gedit, with and without check in "Run executable files when they are opened."

Comment: maybe try changing default application for this file in properties? At least on my machine, the default is set to GNU Emacs, and yet i still can run scripts from a folder

Comment: Ive installed the GNU Emacs but if i start it, it opens the codeeditor of GNU Emacs. Isnt there a faster way?